# Creating a simple login using XML to store the data

Tags: android, xml, authentication, sharedpreferences, android-xml

Hello one question I have which I can’t find the solution to is I want to create a login for my application so that single user can login. As I intend only one person to be using the application I wanted to avoid using php and HTTPS. Every example I have seen so far is connecting via some database which I don’t think we need to do as only user will tend to use the app.

I was thinking more along the lines of having a one off registration page for the user when he first downloads the application and when he register stores the username and password in XML.  Then allow the user to login where the user will check XML file to see if its correct if so let the user go to the main page, as well as use preference to avoid login if the user wishes to do so.

So my main question is this possible? Saving data using XML when registering and checking against that data in XML when logging in.  If so how do I go towards implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not you use [SharedPrefernces](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) (or) sqllite for this purpose? I think using SharedPrefernces will avoid having XML parsing and all that logic.

Comment: Just keep in mind that if you simply use SharedPreferences, you're storing credentials in a plane-text form, which is extremely bad. There's unofficial ObsfuscatedSharedPreferences implementation class which offers a basic encryption/decryption to what you store in SharedPreferences, but overall I don't think it's a good idea to store that on the phone itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure where you're storing this XML, but I'm going to assume you just want to store the user credentials on the phone, and not connect to a remote database to do this.

I would strongly advise against this, as the paradigm - at least in my mind - is that whatever I do on my phone is stored remotely somewhere.

Imagine I create an account in your application, and continually log into it, and one day either change my phone, or reset my content. I'd expect, because of the registration and login process, that I can simply re-download the application and log into it without any data loss. What you're essentially doing is presenting me with a faux registration and don't sync any of my information to a remote destination. I'd be extremely unhappy if I used an application that made me register an account, only to find out none of my information was backed up on your servers.